# Do I have to create a contact entry for *myself* to use Siri?

Tags: ios, siri

Siri keeps telling me "I know nothing of you who are or where you live"

Answer (score 3):

Yes you do. Siri uses the contact information from the contact you select in Settings → General → Siri → My Info.

[image]

If you do not have a contact selected there, Siri will not know your address, etc.

Comment: no I enabled location services for siri and now it works